# How to convert URL string into java.io.File in Android

Tags: java, android, java.nio.file

I am overriding the `android.webkit.WebViewClient` method `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)` in a custom class. In some cases, the `url` parameter points to an encrypted local file, in the form `file:///path/to/file.extension`. I need to convert the String `url` into a `java.io.File` to decrypt it.
How do I reliably convert the `url` parameter into a valid path to pass into `new File(path)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
new File(new URL(url).toURI());
```

but that would only work if URL is not hierarchical, which is your case. (For example you cannot do it if the URL points to a file in JAR file).

Comment: I don't think this will work because the parameter `url` is not a `java.net.Url`, it is a `java.lang.String`.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking, this will just create a File Object and not download the entire file from URL right?

Answer (score 1):

File constructor does accept [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29), so try something like:

```
File file = new File(new URL("file:///path/to/file.extension").toURI());
System.out.println(file);
Output:
\path\to\file.extension
```